# The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

Tags: java, jsp, generics, arraylist

We have using JSP page with JDK1.6 with Eclipse indigo and server Jboss 4.2.
My JSP Page is :

```
<%@ page import="org.java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%!ArrayList<IssueRequestType> requestType_list = new ArrayList<IssueRequestType>();
```

When we compile jsp page,we have getting error like

> "The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with
>   arguments".

Please help me...

Comment: Its `import="java.util.ArrayList"`

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
<%@ page import="org.java.util.ArrayList" %>
```

to

```
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%!java.util.ArrayList<IssueRequestType> requestType_list = 
                                         new java.util.ArrayList<IssueRequestType>();
```

Comment: After changing same issue.thank you for helping.<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>

Comment: Targeting JDK version should be greater than or equal to `1.5`

Comment: Now I am using JDK 1.6.

Comment: Are you using any other third party `ArrayList`? If yes then use `java.util.ArrayList<IssueRequestType>`

Comment: No sir,i am using actual arrayList.

Comment: Check whether you are using `1.6` or not. From cmd: `java -version`. If you are Eclipse check it in `Build Path`.

Comment: I am getting same error "The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments"